# TypeScript/JSX Type Assertion works only outside JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a react component that maps through an array.

Each array item has an optional ID type.

If I have this ID, I will render an element, otherwise nothing.

This element has an onClick that calls a function accepts the ID as param.

Even though I check if I have the ID, TypeScript still complains that the ID might be undefined, but only inside the onClick method, not outside (see the code sample)

Why is that? How can I make this error go away?

[Please see the error on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&jsx=2#code/PTAEDMEMGsFNQEYEsB2ATVBzAzgWAFBqwDGANpAE7wqQC2s2ADpMfAEqwsAuoA3gaAgBXFMS5IA9ilDEqkLrACipWPRRcAFAEoAXKEgoAngG4CAXwIEQoACoALJNlBdDjeHchODoCY3FTIUlBGCl8CFzdQAGU6RhUbV3gAXj4BUCQ0AH49bC4KLFN8QRp6HLyC80t8Yilc0GxYlQBBCgpIQz0Y2jjYBLcAbQBdUBT+3gy9AHIFXMmAGlAS2CmmtHyDSbMF3iWpgDFSCSpsYiFNwarwETFJaQbulT3r-xQNCfrylEwtfiKZWokKgAdIdMBpJgBJAAi83SaC0hQs+AIV1EL2ijVgAGEJN0pLB1NpUn8qFwhBRpBo0oIADwYABuAD5qYI+Pcei02oYgbRIIwNG8FLROpi+rAtCNGcTWTL0uBBaogRkJb9ZbL2Y9nrcFbQlfDjKBrPZHKAAO5HaB4P5qwSk8nSGmMHwoLGkJDEaBJXhEpJS3j1TFPNHapBCvUI0BmMyM8ZhpZmGnARiMg0gI0OJxoCQMRYSHjmijQFkypFqsxaUusxMM5l-LTmQoEGooOpZ2gjUA0ro9HF4lAEnjAFNAA):

[image]

```js
// fake bindings
declare namespace React {
  function createElement(): any;
}

// This type has an optional prop
type SampleType = {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
}

const sampleArray: SampleType[] = [{id: 'test', name: 'Adrian'}, {name: 'Florescu'}]

function sampleFunction(id: string){
  console.log('ID', id);
}

function SampleComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      {sampleArray.map((item: SampleType) => {
        if(item.id) {
          sampleFunction(item.id); // This works
          return <p onClick={() => { sampleFunction(item.id); }}>{item.name}</p>; //// This does not work
        }
      })}
    </div>
  )
};

const dom = <SampleComponent />;
```

Comment: When you posted your question, I noticed you posted the TypeScript playground link "raw" (so it was both a link and text). I edited to make it just a link with a text label, and it broke. I managed to fix it, but couldn't understand why it broke. I've [found the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-link). Just mentioning it because for now, if you want to do links to TypeScript's new playground, you'll need to do that workaround.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not JSX, it's timing. :-) Since the click happens later, it's entirely possible (from TypeScript's perspective) that `id` may have *become* `undefined` between when you checked it and when you are using it where a `string` is expected. The same thing would happen here:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  sampleFunction(item.id); // Same error occurs
}, 1000);
```

The solution is to make that not possible. One option is to capture `id` (and while we're there, we may as well capture `name`):

```
if(item.id) {
  const {id, name} = item;
  return <p onClick={() => { sampleFunction(id); }}>{name}</p>; // This works now
}
```

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&jsx=2#code/PTAEDMEMGsFNQEYEsB2ATVBzAzgWAFBqwDGANpAE7wqQC2s2ADpMfAEqwsAuoA3gaAgBXFMS5IA9ilDEqkLrACipWPRRcAFAEoAXKEgoAngG4CAXwIEQoACoALJNlBdDjeHchODoCY3FTIUlBGCl8CFzdQAGU6RhUbV3gAXj4BUCQ0AH49bC4KLFN8QRp6HLyC80t8Yilc0GxYlQBBCgpIQz0Y2jjYBLcAbQBdUBT+3gy9AHIFXMmAGlAS2CmmtHyDSbMF3iWpgDFSCSpsYiFNwarwETFJaQbulT3r-xQNCfrylEwtfiKZWokKgAdIdMBpJgBJAAi83SaC0hQs+AIV1EL2ijVgAGEJN0pLB1NpUn8qFwhBRpBo0oIADwYABuAD5qYI+Pcei02oYgbRIIwNG8FLROpi+rAtCNGcTWTL0uBBaogRkJb9ZbKaig6uM0AslmYRukhYU1TLSeTpDTGD4UFjSEhiNAkrwiUkpbx6pinmjbm94cZQGYzIydnRYGYacBGIz-SBrPZHKA0BIGIsJDwAO5HaAsmVItVmLR51kRhnMv5acyFAgaupJ2gGmldHo4vEoAk8YDRoA)

Comment: Makes sense T.J. Crowder, Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu - It was a fun one. :-)